# How to augment data using tflite_model_maker?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, image-classification

I'm using tflite_model_maker 0.4.2 to train an imager classifier like this:

```
from tflite_model_maker import model_spec
from tflite_model_maker import image_classifier
from tflite_model_maker.config import ExportFormat
from tflite_model_maker.config import QuantizationConfig
        
...

data = DataLoader.from_folder(src_directory)

train_data, rest_data = data.split(0.8)
validation_data, test_data = rest_data.split(0.5)

model = image_classifier.create(train_data, model_spec=model_spec.get('efficientnet_lite0'), validation_data=validation_data, epochs = EPOCHS)

loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(test_data)
```

How can I augment the data before training? I want to add noise, blur, exposure and image flipping.

Comment: did you try - https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/data_augmentation

Comment: I'm using tf_model_maker, so I can't actually use that. Here's the documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/api_docs/python/tflite_model_maker/image_classifier